# How to combine a field from multiple tables into a single field in a MySQL View?

Tags: mysql, join, view

I have multiple tables, each with a `code` field.  I'd like to combine all the values in the separate `code` fields into a new View in a single `code` field.  I only want distinct code values in the view. There are codes in each table that don't exist in any of the other tables, and there are codes in each table that exist in all the other tables.

What I'm trying to do with fake SQL that doesn't work:

```
CREATE VIEW codes AS
SELECT table_a.code AS code, table_b.code AS code, table_n.code AS code
FROM table_a, table_b, table_n;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need [`UNION`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/union.html):

```
create view codes as
select code from table_a
union select code from table_b
union select code from table_n
```

Please note by default, `UNION` is `UNION DISTINCT`: it removes duplicates. If you want to keep them, use `UNION ALL`.